# How do I put characters inbetween characters

Tags: python

```py
word2 = input("put in the word you want me to repeat: ")
letter = ""
print("The original string is: " + word2)

for x in range(len(word2)):
    letter += word2[x]
```

So if i put in `"dwas"` it will just print `"dwas"`. How do I make it print `"d-ww-aaa-ssss"`?

Comment: `'-'.join(letter * (idx + 1) for idx, letter in enumerate(word2))`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your question there is a 'delete' link just below the question text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate` passing the string value from input, and the start value as `1`, then repeat the characters `n` times, and finally join by `-`:

```py
>>> print('-'.join(v*i for v,i in enumerate(inp,1)))
d-ww-aaa-ssss
```

Answer (score 1):

By composiing built-in functions:

```
s = "hallo"
new_s = '-'.join(map(str.__mul__, s, range(1, len(s)+1)))
print(new_s)
#h-aa-lll-llll-ooooo
```

---

A for *loop* approach similar to the one in the question

```
s = "hallo"

# construct the output character per character
new_s = ''
# iterate over (index, character)-pairs, index start from 1 
for i, char in enumerate(s, 1):
    # add to output i-times the same character followed by -
    new_s += f'{char*i}-'

# remove the last character (always the -)
new_s = new_s.rstrip('-')

# check result
print(new_s)
```